# Route Interception with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am building an application in AngularJS using Firebase as the "backend".

I am wanting to make it so you have to login to the application to see anything.

I want to use Firebase User Authentication System.

I am using the `routeProvider` to route my application.

My question is how do you restrict these routes to logged in users and only allow non-logged in users to see the login page?

My routes look like this: ( in short)

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'firebase', 'components', 'ng-breadcrumbs', 'clients'])

.constant('fbUrl', 'https://my-billing.firebaseio.com/')

.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        // Pages //
        .when('/', {
            //controller:'DashboardController as dashboard',
            templateUrl:'pages/dashboard.html',
        })
        .when('/dashboard', {
            //controller:'DashboardController as dashboard',
            templateUrl:'pages/dashboard.html',  
            label: 'Dashboard',
        })
        .when('/settings', {
            //controller:'SettingsController as settings',
            templateUrl:'pages/settings.html',  
            label: 'Settings',
        })
```

My login function looks like this:

```
angular.module('auth', ["firebase"])

.constant('fbUrl', 'https://my-billing.firebaseio.com/')

.controller('authController', function($scope, Firebase, $firebaseArray, fbUrl) {

    var auth = this;
    var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl);

    auth.password = function() {
        ref.authWithPassword({
            email    : auth.email,
            password : auth.password
        }, function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Login Failed!", error);
            } else {
                console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: You first need to create a service for handling fire base authentication.  Are you using angularfire?

Comment: Look at this https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-routers

Comment: Apparently I am completely blind. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a resolve function for every route.

The resolve function should check the permissions of the user, and if the user does not have permission to access the route, you should redirect the user to another page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already knew that. Have no freaking clue how to do it. everything I find online uses $stateProvider rather than $routeProvider and I'm highly irritated with this. If I was building this with Codeigniter and MYSQL I would be past it already. First hurdle I've had with angular js

Comment: Can you give me an example of how one might look? If I got that I could probably get it to work with mine.